# Compare gps positions

Tags: iphone, annotations, location, mkmapview

i have never worked with MKMapView or CoreLocation before so I need some help.
I want to get my current position (maybe show this position in a mapView) and update my position periodically and compare my new and old position every time to see if i have moved.

Is something like this possible? How can I do this? I have already implemented a MKMapView. But I am not sure how I could get my current position and make a comparison to see if i am moving...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple. Set `showsUserLocation` to `YES` and you're done. [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html)

To make it a little nicer you can center the `MKMapView` every time the position changes. See [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Maps_on_the_iPad_with_MapKit_and_the_MKMapView_Class_%28Xcode_4%29#Updating_the_Map_View_based_on_User_Movement) how to do it.

If you want to know if you have moved, you should store the most recent position in a property and then in the delegate method `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` check if the new location is different from the last location.

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D locationCoordinate;
...
@synthesize locationCoordinate = _locationCoordinate;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    if (userLocation.coordinate.latitude != self.locationCoordinate.latitude ||
        userLocation.coordinate.longitude != self.locationCoordinate.longitude) {
        // We moved
    }
    self.locationCoordinate = userLocation.coordinate;
}
```

I'm actually not sure if the delegate method is only called when the `userLocation` has changed. In that case you don't have to store the location as a property and do the check, just implement the delegate method and do your stuff there.

Comment: that sounds very good! thanks, i will have a try now. But is it also possible to tolerate a little deviation? For example 100 meters or something like that? Cause i could not imagine that the gps-system works always accurate enough...

Comment: Ahh...but i think the latitude and longitude are to float values, aren't they? is maybe a comparison like this possible?

if ((userLocation.coordinate.latitude - self.locationCoordinate) >=12 &&(userLocation.coordinate.latitude - self.locationCoordinate) <= 12))

Comment: Sure that's possible to do if you remember to use the longitude and latitude properties of self.locationCoordinate. 12 seems like a huge value, though. Remember you are comparing geographical locations and not lengths. If you absolutely need to compare the distance in terms of meters you could implement the Haversine formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula